# Fastest way to sum up in a dictionary with specified (and ordered) keys

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, sum

What is the fastest way to sum up values in a dictionary, where you need to specify the keys (so not sum the entire values of the dictionary).

For example, let's say I have the following dictionary:

```
dict_1 = {1: 128, 2: 134, 3: 45, 4: 104, 5: 129}
```

and I want to sum up the values in keys 3 through 5.
In this example, the result is `45+104+129 = 278`.

How can I do this as fast as possible?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
m = 3
s = 5
summation = 0.
while m <= s:
    summation += dict_1[m]
    m += 1
```

It works, but I'm looking for a faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution (assuming all the keys exist):

```py
sum(map(dict_1.get, range(3, 5+1)))
```

This solution is generally faster than the others:

```
For the example provided in the question:
 - this solution:   270 ns
 - bb1:             446 ns
 - Gwang-Jin Kim:   356 ns
 - MrGre4a:         244 ns

Dict of 1,000 elements and 20 values fetched:
 - this solution:   526 ns
 - bb1:           36200 ns  (slow because it walks through the whole dict)
 - Gwang-Jin Kim:   965 ns
 - MrGre4a:         879 ns
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(dct[x] for x in range(3, 5+1))
```

Comment: This will fail if one of the keys are missing.

Comment: `dct.get(x, 0)` then instead of `dct[x]`. But it was not condition that it should go on when one of keys missing.

Comment: using get might be better then dct[x] - even better would simply be : 

`sum(v for k,v in dct.items() if k in range(3,6))` 

This way there is no hit to access `get()` when you know the key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution also could be:

```
m = 3
s = 5
summation = int()
for i in range(m, s+1):
    summation += dict_1[i]
```

Comment: The code does not work: there is a typo in the loop on `summ`

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(v for k, v in dict_1.items() if 3 <= k <= 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Q : *So what is the fastest way to sum up values in a dictionary, **where you need to specify the keys** (so not sum the entire values of the dictionary).*

I suppose you also mean the general case...

```py
d = {1: 128, 2: 134, 3: 45, 4: 104, 5: 129}

keys = range(3, 5+1) # case described by Gwang-Jin Kim
res = sum(d[i] for i in keys if i in d)
print(res)
# 278

keys = [1,3,5] # general case (not necessarily between two bounds)
res = sum(d[i] for i in keys if i in d)
print(res)
# 302
```

Comment: test key in dictionary taking into account Tony Sufolk 66 remarks...